# Beginner trying to get jQuery anythingSlider to show up on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm brand-new to jQuery.  Tried to use this snippet to create an anythingSlider, but I just get the images without the slider.  The div of images is defined elsewhere and all the file paths are correct.  I changed the width of the PolicyContainer just to verify jQuery was working.  Is there anything wrong with this code?  What's the most likely problem?

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js">         
    </script>
    <script src="/anythingSlider/jquery.anythingslider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var test = $('#PolicyContainer').width(300);
        $('#slider').anythingSlider();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I know you mentioned that the paths are correct, but is the page linking to the anythingslider script and the "anythingSslider" directory on the same level of directory?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `anythingslider.css` file? It has essential css styling that positions the slides and hides non-current ones.

I would expect to see something like this in the header:

```
<link href="/anythingSlider/anythingslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/anythingSlider/jquery.anythingslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = $('#PolicyContainer').width(300);
    $('#slider').anythingSlider();
});
</script>
```

If you are including the stylesheet, make sure that the `slider` ID exists.

Now if it still isn't working, it might be a javascript error. So if you are testing in a modern browser, press F12 and look at the console tab for any errors.